# Get text of active BS pill

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Since I'm a total noob and haven't found an answer here or on google.

I need to get the text of the active BS pill, however doing this:

```
$('.nav-pills').on('click',function(){
                                        alert($('.nav-pills .active').text())
                                        });
```

Gives me the text of the already active pill, even though a change has occurred.

I can offset this with a delay, but I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this:

```
$('.nav-pills').on('click',function(){
                                        setTimeout(function(){alert($('.nav-pills .active').text())},1);
                                        });
```

Comment: Use the `shown.bs.tab` event on the tab. See https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#events

Comment: Your handler is running before the BS handler that changes the active tab.

Answer (score 0):

@linquefire you can use the below two events based on your needs.

//after the tab toggled

```
   $("#myTab").on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
        alert($('.nav.nav-tabs>li.active').text());
   });
```

//before the tab toggled

```
$(".nav.nav-tabs").on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
      alert($('.nav.nav-tabs>li.active').text());
});
```